# unit test service layer - NUnit, NHibernate

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, nunit

I would like to unit test a DEPENDENT service layer which allows me to perform CRUD operation without mocking using NUnit. I know this is probably bad practice but I want to give it a try anyway - even if the tests have to run over night. My data is persisted using NHibernate and I have implemented a little library that 'bootstraps' the database which I could use in a [Setup] method. I am just wondering if someone has done something similar and what the fastest method for bootstrapping the database is. I am using something like this:

```
var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.Configure();
            cfg.AddAssembly("Bla");
            new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false);
```

to establish the db schema. After that I populate some lookup tables from some Excel tables.

Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Christian

Comment: External resources? Those aren't unit tests anymore You are trying to implement but integration tests.

Comment: Ok ok I know. Let us call it test then (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ayende has a good example of this approach in this [blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/28/nhibernate-unit-testing.aspx). His example is shown below with my comments.

As the Configuration is expensive to create, it is created only once per test run. A SQLite in-memory database is used as this is the fastest way to do queries.

```
public class InMemoryDatabaseTest : IDisposable
{
    private static Configuration Configuration;
    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory;
    protected ISession session;

    public InMemoryDatabaseTest(Assembly assemblyContainingMapping)
    {
        if (Configuration == null)
        {
            Configuration = new Configuration()
                .SetProperty(Environment.ReleaseConnections,"on_close")
                .SetProperty(Environment.Dialect, typeof (SQLiteDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                .SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionDriver, typeof(SQLite20Driver).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                .SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionString, "data source=:memory:")
                .SetProperty(Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, typeof (ProxyFactoryFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                .AddAssembly(assemblyContainingMapping);

            SessionFactory = Configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
        }

        session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();

        new SchemaExport(Configuration).Execute(true, true, false, true, session.Connection, Console.Out);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        session.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When using this, each test starts by creating required data.

```
public class BlogTestFixture : InMemoryDatabaseTest
{
    public BlogTestFixture() : base(typeof(Blog).Assembly)
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public void CanSaveAndLoadBlog()
    {
        object id;

        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            id = session.Save(new Blog
            {
                AllowsComments = true,
                CreatedAt = new DateTime(2000,1,1),
                Subtitle = "Hello",
                Title = "World",
            });

            tx.Commit();
        }

        session.Clear();


        using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var blog = session.Get<Blog>(id);

            Assert.Equal(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), blog.CreatedAt);
            Assert.Equal("Hello", blog.Subtitle);
            Assert.Equal("World", blog.Title);
            Assert.True(blog.AllowsComments);

            tx.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When writing such **Integration Tests**, the most important things to keep in mind that you should still

- **automate** as much as possible (preferrably everything), which includes setting up the database and deleting it again after use
- avoid the [General Fixture](http://xunitpatterns.com/Obscure%20Test.html) antipattern, which means that each test case should start with an empty database, and itself fill in appropriate rows using [Back Door Manipulation](http://xunitpatterns.com/Back%20Door%20Manipulation.html).

I have written about [my own experiences with testing against databases](http://blogs.msdn.com/ploeh/archive/2008/01/31/DataAccessComponentTestingRedux.aspx) several times in the past.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at this.